# Disabling Split Option in iOS5 Keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I am facing problem in my app because of the new split keyboard option in iOS5.

Is there any way we can hide or disable this option in objective C?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you fix the problem?

Comment: Or say what the problem is and maybe we can help?

Comment: there is no option for that. and i'm sure there will no option be available in the future.

Comment: We have created a custom texteditor and successfully finished the project. But we dont need the splited keyboard, because it creates problem in our custom view.

Comment: Why don't you fix the problem in your custom view?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the split keyboard does not use the same functions as regular keyboard. see here.

[missing kb notifications](http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2012/05/the-ipad-split-keyboard-and-missing-notifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: You can iterate through the keyboard subviews and hide the button but you can't control the state of the keyboard when going from one app to the next. It would get really tricky and sneaky to force the private api to call when the application did enter foreground and the keyboard became active.

You could do this but apple may deny you from the store.

Fix your view to account for the keyboard movement. Your users will dock or unsplit the keyboard when there's clear disruption in the UI due to the keyboard placement.

Other solutions could be to move the entire view that requires keyboard placement to be docked or undocked using the notifications. See other posting here: [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100443/has-anyone-found-a-good-way-of-using-the-new-ios5-keyboard-events)