# Is there a way to disable "undocking" of the keyboard?

Tags: ipad, ios5

Is there any way to disable the "undock" feature of `UIKeyboard` in iOS 5.0 and above?

Right now my *whole view* moves up and it looks very jittery when the user activates the undocking.

Comment: maybe this could help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100443/has-anyone-found-a-good-way-of-using-the-new-ios5-keyboard-events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100443/has-anyone-found-a-good-way-of-using-the-new-ios5-keyboard-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new iPad iOS 5 only feature and you can't disable it.

Comment: Ya rckones i was unable to find anything on net for the same. Hope apple gets rid of this in next version :) .

Comment: @RickyMehra2012 don't bet on it, I for one really like the slipt keyboard.